# Codeigniter routes.php Controllers are not working with lowercase

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I redirected my controllers to lowercase in `.htaccess`, but after redirecting to lowercase I am getting error as shown below.

[image]

My **Controllers** file name is: `Seo_Services.php`

My **routes.php** file declaration is:

```php
    $route['seo-services'] = 'Seo_Services';
```

**Note:** This works on localhost. Not working on Godaddy hosting panel.

Please Help!

**Edited:**
Note: To make it more clear, I just want my url to be lowercase.

**Working:** https://immacbytes.com/Seo-Services

**Not Working:** https://immacbytes.com/seo-services

Answer (score 0):

**Codeigniter Controller Example and naming conventions**

```
<?php
class Blog extends CI_Controller {

        public function index()
        {
                echo 'Hello World!';
        }
}
```

*The file must be called ‘Blog.php’, with a capital ‘B’.*

*Class names must start with an uppercase letter.*

This is valid:

```
<?php
class Blog extends CI_Controller {

}
```

This is not valid:

```
<?php
class blog extends CI_Controller {

}
```

Please check and revert.

Comment: Sorry Bimal Kumar, I think you have not understand my question. I know that controller must start with a capital alphabet. Everything is working, I just want my url from https://immacbytes.com/Seo-Services to https://immacbytes.com/seo-services.

Comment: My url works with Seo-Services. But I want to lower it to .i.e seo-services.

Answer (score 0):

I just knew that my `web.config` is wrong. I was passing a rule to redirect Seo-Services to seo-services. Rule is shown below:

```
<rule name="bfgfgg-fgfg-g-ff" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="Seo-Services" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="seo-services" />
</rule>
```

May be the `web.config` rule are not **case sensitive**. So this rule was getting triggered again & again. In result I was getting error.

Thanks!